# Reading binary file data into an array and sorting it

Tags: arrays, file, sorting

Sup, guys. I really need some help with my code. So, i`ve created 2 binary files and I need to create a third file which contains data from 2 previous files in sorted manner (structure of a file is number(int) and text(char), and file needs to be sorted in ascending manner by number (the text must follow the number).

Here`s an example(don't mind the commas):

**file1.txt:**

1 text1,
7 text2,
4 text3

**file2.txt:**

3 text4,
8 text5,
2 text6

**so the file 3 should be:**

1 text1,
2 text6,
3 text4,
4 text3,
7 text2,
8 text5

So far i have, like I said, created 2 binary files which have a number and text written into them. I've also kinda written the content of files into an array. The issue is - I have no idea how to sort them and put them into file.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class faili {
int atslega;
char * komponente;

public:
faili(int x, char * s) {
    komponente = new char[20];
    strcpy(komponente, s);
    atslega = x;
}
faili() {
    komponente = new char[20];
    atslega = 0;
}

void writeToFile(fstream & f) {
    f.write((char *)&atslega, sizeof(int));
    f.write(komponente, 20);
}

void readFromFile(fstream & f) {
    f.read((char *)&atslega, sizeof(int));
    f.read(komponente, 20);
}

int getKey() {
    return atslega;
}

void printIt() {
    cout << atslega << " " << komponente << endl;
}
};

typedef vector<faili *> failiMas;
void printMas(failiMas arr) {
    for (failiMas::iterator it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); it++) {
        (*it)->printIt();
    }
};

class salidzinat {
public:
bool operator()(faili * i1, faili * i2) {
    return i1->getKey() > i2->getKey();

 }
 };


    typedef vector<faili *> failiMas;

    int main() {

        ofstream outputFile1w("f1.txt");

        /*faili * i1 = new faili(1, "sad");
        faili * i2 = new faili(3, "asdasd");
        faili * i3 = new faili(6, "dfgdfc");
        faili * i4 = new faili(4, "dija");
        faili * i5 = new faili(8, "yjk");
        faili * i6 = new faili(2, "ruifjer");
        */

        faili ier1(1, "sad");
        faili ier2(3, "asdasd");
        faili ier3(6, "dfgdfn");
        faili ier4(4, "dija");
        faili ier5(8, "yjk");
        faili ier6(2, "ruifjer");

        fstream f1("f1.txt");

        ier1.writeToFile(f1);
        ier2.writeToFile(f1);
        ier3.writeToFile(f1);

        f1.close();

        f1.open("f1.txt");

        faili a, b, c;

        a.readFromFile(f1);
        b.readFromFile(f1);
        c.readFromFile(f1);

        cout << "Faila f1.txt saturs: \n";

        a.printIt();
        b.printIt();
        c.printIt();

        f1.close();

        ofstream outputFile2w("f2.txt");

        fstream f2("f2.txt");

        ier4.writeToFile(f2);
        ier5.writeToFile(f2);
        ier6.writeToFile(f2);

        f2.close();

        f2.open("f2.txt");

        faili d, e, f;

        d.readFromFile(f2);
        e.readFromFile(f2);
        f.readFromFile(f2);

        cout << "Faila f2.txt saturs: \n";

        d.printIt();
        e.printIt();
        f.printIt();

        f2.close();

        ifstream inputFile1r;
        inputFile1r.open("f1.txt", ios::in);
        int count = 0;
        string textarr[5];
        string textsave = "Null";

        while (!inputFile1r.eof()) {
            inputFile1r >> textsave;
            textarr[count] = textsave;

            cout << textarr[count] << endl;
            count++;
        }
        inputFile1r.close();

        ifstream inputFile2r;
        inputFile2r.open("f2.txt", ios::in);;

        while (!inputFile2r.eof()) {
            inputFile2r >> textsave;
            textarr[count] = textsave;

            cout << textarr[count] << endl;
            count++;
        }
        system("Pause");

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    };
```

I, of course, don't need you to do a homework for me :P. I just kinda want to know if I'm thinking correctly and what am i supposed to do next as I`m quite lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eof() condition inside a loop and keep track of all the numbers. If a new number comes up that is greater than 'greatest', you move it ahead in the array. There are a number of sorting techniques you can use but this is the most basic one. Once you have the sorted array, you could simply write the data in third file.

```
#include <unistd.h>
int c;
int greatest = 0;
int arr = new int[N];

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    faili l;
    string s = l.readFromFile(file);
    int num = atoi(s);

    #Compare with greatest and write in array

}
```